# Why Android emulator can't access API from online server?

Tags: android, api, http, react-native, https

I'm facing a problem which is my App can access API from `iOS simulator` but it doesn't on `Android emulator`.

I call the API like this :

```
async fetchData() {    
    let url = `http://1**.***.***.***/bla/bla`;

    try{
        let response = await fetch(url,{
            headers: {
                'x-application-id':'123',
                'hashing': this.hashGenerator("message"),
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "location":"city"
            })
        });
        if(!response.ok){
            throw new Error(response.status)
        } else {
            return await response.json();
        }
    } catch(error) {
        this.setState({ loadingList: false });
    }
}
```

Is it because I use `http` instead of `https` ?

I've been stuck since yesterday...

Comment: `http//1**.***.***.***` is an IP address. Make sure it is available from Android emulator. I wonder if it is `127.0.0.1`

Comment: how can I make it available ?

Comment: it's not `127.0.0.1`..

Comment: first check if that URL is available from the Android emulator's web browser

Comment: try to access your server from web browser application in Android emulator, let us know if that's working

Comment: yes..it's working.. then what should I do ?

Comment: then you probably need to check if your app has INTERNET permission. I unfortunately have no idea how to check it for react-native

Comment: I have this in my AndroidManisfet.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: You need a colon in the URL, after the http   -  let url = 'http://1**.***.***.***/bla/bla';

Comment: @GregHNZ yeah, I've fixed it..still the same.. but I tried to fetch another API using `https` it works.. any idea how to enable request using `http` ?

Comment: What error does fetch throw? Post the error message.

Comment: @RaviRaj the code is `403`

Comment: By the way, 403 error code stands for forbidden. Do your server allow permission to access the URL from Android OS?. Check if you have made any mistake in your headers, may be due to hard coding. I don't think HTTP or HTTPS makes any difference in Android.

Answer (score 0):

For `http` requests, certificate signing is required. you can use the following code to trust all certificates for your app. As your app is using your server only, there should not be any security issue using this code.

```
public void trustAllCertificates() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                    return myTrustedAnchors;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Just call this function in your `Application` class or in your main `Activity`.

Comment: where should I put this code ? Inside of my `MainActivity`?

Comment: I call the function inside of `protected String getMainComponentName() {}`.. is it correct ?